# What is a good Pokemon that has the ability Drizzle?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I am building a Drizzle team (All Pokemon gain boosts from rain) for Pokemon X and Y. What non-banned Pokemon gets the ability naturally? This Pokemon has to be one that is available for random online battles and following legendary rules.

Comment: Side note: Rain (and other weather effects) got a fairly decent nerf in Pokemon X/Y - Weather caused by Drizzle/Sand stream etc no longer last 'forever', they run out just like Rain Dance and Sandstorm. Keep this in mind if you're reading about tactics from Generation 5 (Black/White)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Drizzle), only Politoed and Kyogre can have Drizzle, and Politoed only gets it as a hidden ability.

Answer (score 0):

Politoed is a good pokemon that has the ability drizzle. The only thing is, Politoed only gets drizzle as a hidden ability.