# How do I get a Drizzle Politoed?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-series

After asking a previous [***question***](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146879/what-is-a-good-pokemon-that-has-the-ability-drizzle) , I realized that Politoed is the only non-Kyogre Pokemon who can get Drizzle, but as a hidden ability. How can I get drizzle without friend safari?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Poliwag does appear in hordes in the Pokemon Village, but Poliwhirl with better stats and chances at a hidden ability can be found in Friend Safaris. If you want a Drizzle Politoed, you'll have to find a Water-type Friend Safari that contains Poliwhirl and catch one whose ability is *Swift Swim*.

Once you have said Poliwhirl, evolving it to Politoed should have it end up with the *Drizzle* ability.

Comment: Poliwag actually *does* appear in hordes in the Pokémon Village.

Answer (score 5):

You can get Poliwhirl from the Friend Safari if you have a friend who is Water type who has beaten the Elite Four. This will have a good chance of having the hidden ability if you are online at the same time as your friend; a Poliwhirl with Swift Swim will evolve into a Politoed with Drizzle.

Source: [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/xy/friendsafari.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

As I know from previous experience hidden abilities are only obtainable through hordes, friend safari and breeding. I suggest using a Pokemon with rain dance and use it in a horde of poliwag or whirls and the ones that have swift swim will raise their speed.

Answer (score -2):

Go to route 19 keep fishing with super rod and be patient it will take some time

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. To improve your answer, could you please expand upon it?

Comment: The fishing provides Politoeds with one of standard abilities (Water Absorb or Damp), which is not Drizzle.